# Hahn-Banach Theorems Applications

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

Please, if anyone can help me with some useful tips to solve this aim:

Let $K^1,...,K^n$ closed convex sets containing the origin of a normed space $E$, and let $c_1,...c_n$ positive real numbers. Prove that, if $x\in E$ cannot be of the form $x=c_1x_1+⋯c_nx_n$ for all $x_i\in K_i, i=1,...,n$, then there is $f\in E^{\ast}$  (the dual of $E$) such that $f(x)>1$ and $f(y)≤1/c_i$ for all $y\in K_{i}$ and i$=1,...,n$.

The book suggested to consider $K=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}K_{i}$, prove that $K$ is closed and convex and apply the geometric version. BUT, I simply cannot see how $K$ will be closed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\sum c_iK_i$ need not be closed. Let $C$ consist of $\{0\}$ and the points $\frac  1 n e^{\frac i n}$ in $\mathbb C$. Let $K$ be the convex hull of $C$. Since $C$ is compact it follows that $K$ is compact and convex containing the origin. Now $e^{1/n}=n\frac  1 n e^{\frac i n} \to 1$and $1 \notin \{cx: c\geq 0,x \in K\}$. [This is because $\Im z>0$ for all $z \in \{cx: c\geq 0,x \in K\}$].

Comment: why is $\sum c_i$ equal to $1$?

Comment: I think the book wanted to restrict $c_i$'s to those satisfying $\sum c_i=1$ but forgot to mention that explicitly.  @Matematleta

Comment: If you put this restriction on $c_i$'s you can use the fact that $(c_1,c_2,...,c_n,x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \to \sum c_ix_i$ is a continuous function on a compact set and hence its image is compact.

Comment: Well, $\frac1n e^{\frac in}\to 0$ not to $1$.

Comment: @Berci There was a typo. I have edited my answer. Thanks for pointing out.